# Conference Template Error on Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I've tried to create an Ionic project on "Noje.js command prompt", but an error appeared while downloading the files from github ":heavy_multiplication_x: Downloading - failed!
Error: Timeout of 25000ms reached for https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/archive/master.tar.gz". What should I do? I do need the conference template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using command line with node commands, go with this command
Open terminal or commandline and run this:

`git clone https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app.git`

after this project will be cloned and than :
Want to use TypeScript? Both the master branch and the typescript branch now use TypeScript.

Run `npm install` from the project root.

Install the ionic CLI `(npm install -g ionic)`

Run `ionic serve` in a terminal from the project root.

That's it. it will surely work now.